# css3 way to create design dashed box

Tags: css, dotted-line

I have this design for a dashed box:

[image]

what is the best way to create this with css3?

I have tried to use the 'border:dashed' - but it's not looking like the design I need.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with only css without using background image

Comment: Does anyone know why the (apparently correct) answers are being down-voted? I'm voting to close the question, as no effort has been shown and no code is offered as context of the question, but if seems as if those trying to help are being penalised according to the question's lack of merit.

Comment: Agreed. Since the OP was edited to indicate that using the answers supplied is 'not looking like the design I need'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to realize it with two DIV boxes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#outside {
width:400px;
height:150px;
border-style:dashed; border-width:3px;
position: relative; 
}
#inside {
background-color: white;
width:404px;
height:154px;
position: absolute;
top:-2px;
left:-2px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="outside">
<div id="inside">
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RH5R3/

Comment: thanks ! this look much lie the design

Comment: So apparently `border-style:dashed; border-width:3px;` is acceptable even though you said `border:dashed` wasn't looking right. Sigh!

Comment: As thicker you make the width of the border of the outside div, as longer the dashed will become. But don't forget to adapt the size of the inside div.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, with `border-width:3px;` the dashes are noticeably longer and spaced apart further. That's what he wanted obviously. This is a pretty neat solution as there's no other way that i know of to change the dashes.

Comment: The solution obviously works, but adding extra markup for the sake of making it a pixel perfect match to the "design" is pretty awful.

Answer (score 3):

```
border:1px dashed grey;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/dz4Qj/)

Answer (score 2):

```
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: dashed 1px gray;  
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Gxys/

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this:

    css:

        #xx {
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px; 
        }


        HTML:

        <div style="border:dotted"" id="xx"></div>
```